# Razor TempData Русские символы

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

Пытаюсь вывести русские символы страницы Razor View в блок javascript.
Исполняемый код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            let message = @TempData["Error"]
            console.log(message);
        </script>
```

Если передаются русские символы, то итог - `let message = &#x44B;&#x444;&#x432;&#x444;&#x44B;&#x432;`
Если передаю английские, то все ок

Comment: Кавычки не забыли? Вот так `let message = "@TempData["Error"]"`

Comment: Тогда будет такой же текст, только в ковычках

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
@Html.Raw("{тут русский текст}")
```